# Grant permissions on the attachments folder of a list

Tags: folder, attachments, 2019, sharepoint-server, unique-permissions

I noticed a strange behaviour when using attachments and folders within sharepoint lists. If I create an item in the root of a list, then move the item in a subfolder where userA has contribute permission, userA won't be able to access the attachments of that item, unless he also has at least read permission at the list level. This seem to happen because the attachments are actually placed in the attachments folder which resides in the list's root. 
I don't want to change the list's permissions and I was thinking if there is any posibility of changing the attachment folder's permissions.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug, running BreakRoleInhertiance()  and ResetRoleInheritance() on the item fixes the problem!